# About how the value is returned using app.set() and app.get()

Tags: javascript, express, acl, loopback

I am releasing access to pages using [connect-roles](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles) and [loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Role-REST-API.html) but I have a pertinent question about how I can collect the customer's role and through the connect-roles to read the session and respond to a route.

Example, when the client logs in I load a string containing the client's role and access it in a function that controls access to pages.

I have this doubt because I'm finalizing a large scale service that usually there are multiple client sessions that are accessed instantly using a same storage and check function.

It would be efficient to store the customer's role using `app.set()` and `app.get()`?

```
  app.get('/session-details', function (req, res) {
    var AccessToken = app.models.AccessToken;
    AccessToken.findForRequest(req, {}, function (aux, accesstoken) {
      // console.log(aux, accesstoken);
      if (accesstoken == undefined) {
        res.status(401);
        res.send({
          'Error': 'Unauthorized',
          'Message': 'You need to be authenticated to access this endpoint'
        });
      } else {
        var UserModel = app.models.user;
        UserModel.findById(accesstoken.userId, function (err, user) {
          // console.log(user);
          res.status(200);
          res.json(user);
          // storage employee role
          app.set('employeeRole', user.accessLevel);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Until that moment everything happens as desired I collect the string loaded with the role of the client and soon after I create a connect-roles function to validate all this.

```
var dsConfig = require('../datasources.json');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (app) {
  var User = app.models.user;
  var ConnectRoles = require('connect-roles');
  const employeeFunction = 'Developer';

  var user = new ConnectRoles({
    failureHandler: function (req, res, action) {
      // optional function to customise code that runs when
      // user fails authorisation
      var accept = req.headers.accept || '';
      res.status(403);
      if (~accept.indexOf('ejs')) {
        res.send('Access Denied - You don\'t have permission to: ' + action);
      } else {
        res.render('access-denied', {action: action});
        // here
        console.log(app.get('employeeRole'));
      }
    }
  });

  user.use('authorize access private page', function (req) {
    if (employeeFunction === 'Manager') {
      return true;
    }
  });

  app.get('/private/page', user.can('authorize access private page'), function (req, res) {
    res.render('channel-new');
  });

  app.use(user.middleware());
};
```

Look especially at this moment, when I use the 
 `console.log(app.get('employeeRole'));` will not I have problems with simultaneous connections?

```
  app.get('/private/page', user.can('authorize access private page'), function (req, res) {
    res.render('channel-new');
  });
```

Example client x and y connect at the same time and use the same function to store data about your session?

Being more specific when I print the string in the `console.log(app.get('employeeRole'));` if correct my doubt, that I have no problem with simultaneous connections I will load a new variable `var employeeFunction = app.get('employeeRole');` so yes my function can use the object containing the role of my client in `if (employeeFunction === 'Any Role')` if the role that is loaded in the string contain the required role the route it frees the page otherwise it uses the callback of `failureHandler`.

My test environment is limited to this type of test so I hope you help me on this xD

Comment: You cannot use `app.set()` for data that is relevant to only one user.  That data will be available server-wide.  Instead, you need to either put the data into a user session object or if just for the purpose of this particular request, then put it on the `req` object.

Comment: type do I have a token if I set a random name next to the user's token to avoid this overlay of data?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what that last comment means.  You should be using a session manager and a session object for persistent user-specific data.  That's the common and best practice.

Comment: Yesss after login I use  `res.cookie('access_token', token.id, { signed: true , maxAge: 300000 });`  to keep sessions

Comment: That's a cookie.  That's not a session manager and doesn't create a session object.

Comment: I usually use this function `AccessToken.findForRequest(req, {}, function (aux, accesstoken) {}` after `UserModel.findById(accesstoken.userId, function (err, user) {}` based in `app.get('/session-details', function (req, res) {}` and then just load `app.set('employeeRole', user.accessLevel);`

Comment: As you said above if is correct my session I have no problems with overlap of data stored in the app.get on simultaneous connection of my clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using app.set you can create a session map(like hashmaps). I have integrated the same in one of my projects and it is working flawlessly. Below is the code for it and how you can access it:

**hashmap.js**

```
var hashmapSession = {};

exports.auth = auth = {
  set : function(key, value){
    hashmapSession[key] = value;
  },
  get : function(key){
    return hashmapSession[key];
  },
  delete : function(key){
    delete hashmapSession[key];
  },
  all : function(){
    return hashmapSession;
  }
};
```

**app.js**

```
var hashmap = require('./hashmap');
var testObj = { id : 1, name : "john doe" };

hashmap.auth.set('employeeRole', testObj);
hashmap.auth.get('employeeRole');
hashmap.auth.all();
hashmap.auth.delete('employeeRole');
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you very much!!! Expiring the time to finish the question I will give you the rep